# How to remove unwanted codes from editor in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In word press editor some codes are visible repeatedly. But in preview it won't come. How do I remove them from editor? I am using wordpress 5.0.3.

```
[vc_row type="full_width_background" full_screen_row_position="middle" scene_position="center" text_color="dark" text_align="left" top_padding="5%" bottom_padding="5%" overlay_strength="0.3" shape_divider_position="bottom" shape_type=""][vc_column column_padding="padding-2-percent" column_padding_position="right" background_color_opacity="1" background_hover_color_opacity="1" column_shadow="none" column_border_radius="none" width="7/12" tablet_text_alignment="default" phone_text_alignment="default" column_border_width="none" column_border_style="solid"][vc_column_text]
<h1>Contact REITIUM</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

In WP those square brackets `[ ... ]`  are used to define a *Shortcode* in the visual editor, which usually generates some code that wouldn't be possible to add in the visual editor (for example galleries, animated objects etc.). Unless you really don't want to show what is generated by them, you shouldn't remove them. If you don't need the stuff they generate, just delete them....

Comment: Thank you Johannes. But my client don't want to show these codes while editing.What can i do for this?

Comment: Nothing really. If you need the contents which those shortcodes generate, you need to use them / leave them in there, there's no way around that.

Comment: Although in that particular situation you gave as an example in your question, that shortcode seems to generate inline CSS. You can try to add that via your stylesheet, if it's possible to find selectors which only address those areas. Or you could add the CSS into the HTML tags as inline CSS in  "text mode". But that's dangerous if a client edits the text later on (might delete the CSS unintentionally since he/she doesn't see it).